# python for each run async function without await and parallel

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing, request

I have 10 links in my CSV which I'm trying to run all at the same time in a loop from getTasks function. However, the way it's working now, it send a request to link 1, waits for it to complete, then link 2, etc, etc. I want the 10 links that I have to run all whenever startTask is called, leading to 10 requests a second.

Anyone know how to code that using the code below? Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import asyncio

def getTasks(tasks):
    for task in tasks:
      asyncio.run(startTask(task))


async def startTask(task):
    
    success = await getProduct(task)
    if success is None:
    return startTask(task)

    success = await addToCart(task)
    if success is None:
    return startTask(task)

    ...
    ...
    ...

getTasks(tasks)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to make your requests sent concurrently, you should use the [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) instead of the `requests` package that blocks I/O. And use the asyncio's semaphore to limit the count of concurrent processes at the same time.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

# read links from CSV
links = [
    ...
]

semaphore = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(10) 
# 10 is the max count of concurrent tasks
# that can be processed at the same time.
# In this case, tasks are requests.

async def async_request(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with semaphore, session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()


async def main():
    result = await asyncio.gather(*[
        async_request(link) for link in links
    ])
    print(result)  # [response1, response2, ...]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: I need main to just call the function startTask(task) and that to be it. Then startTask(task) can recall itself the whole time as stated in the code I posted. I've been playing around with the code you posted but I'm pretty sure it doens't allow me to do that.

Comment: You just described a recursion, but I would not use recursion there as it is going to be run 24/7 and it will require huge resources. just use `while True` and wrap in `try` to make it work after errors.

Comment: Decides to just do it like this and "return" if success is None. Works fine now even though I'm pretty sure its not the best way to do it but its fine for my use case. 
```
    while True:
      await asyncio.gather(*[
          startTask(task) for task in tasks
      ])
      time.sleep(5)

```